# Slack message not sending on 'else' block

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm trying to send myself a message on Slack to clarify that the names of the file match the names in the csv cell.

The issue I'm having is that the message does not send for the `else` block. The output from the print statement is as expected, but I don't know why the Slack message does not send. No errors are provided.

Code and console output below.

```
def send_slack_message(message):

    webhook = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/.....'
    message = {
        "text": f"{message}",
        "blocks":[
            {
                "type": "header",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": f"{message}"
                }
            }]
    }
    return requests.post(webhook, json.dumps(message))


def validate_names(path):

    saved_names = os.listdir(path)

    csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

    cell_names = []
    # loop over the list of csv files
    for f in csv_files:
        # read the csv file
        df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",", on_bad_lines='skip', header=None)
        myMatrix = df[df.columns[0]].to_numpy()
        cell_names.extend(myMatrix.tolist())

    cell_names_csv = list(map(lambda x: x +'.csv', cell_names))
    joined_lists = dict(zip(saved_names, cell_names_csv))

    failed_list = [key for i, key in enumerate(list(joined_lists.keys())) if key != list(joined_lists.values())[i]]

    if list(joined_lists.keys()) == list(joined_lists.values()):
        print(f"Names are good in: {path}")
        send_slack_message(f"Names are good in: {path}")
    else:
        print(f"These names need fixing: {', '.join(failed_list)} || path: {path}")
        send_slack_message(f"These names need fixing: {', '.join(failed_list)} || path: {path}")

validate_names('C:\\Users\\path\\to\\dir')
validate_names('C:\\Users\\path\\to\\dir')
```

Console output:

These names need fixing: weekly_report_67483.csv, weekly_report_49385.csv || path: 'C:\Users\path\to\dir'
Names are good in: 'C:\Users\path\to\dir'

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Seems the print immediately before the send_slack_message call is working but have you checked its all running inside the function? What about running a dummy - just sending what you expect as text without the rest?

Comment: Adding a standard string works. I've narrowed it down to ``{', '.join(failed_list)}``

Comment: Does that work in your print function just above?

Comment: I'd log the `message` param in the `send_slack_message` method, then take that and paste it into [Block Kit Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder). That'll check the syntax and give you any errors that might be in the payload you're sending to the webhook.